# Сортировка постов WordPress по сумме чисел, которые выведены произвольными полями

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет. Вопрос сложный, как по мне, не знаю как решить.

Делаю сайт, в нем имеется 4 рейтинга, 3 оценки забиваются через админку в произвольных полях а 1 - это плагин "kk star ratings". Привходе на страницу, считается рейтинг введенный мной через админку и плагином, рейтинга. Выходит сумма и делится на 4, чтобы получить среднюю оценку.

Так вот. Каким образом можно вывести посты по этой сортировке?
Голова крутом, не понимаю. Как можно произвести вычисление за пределами цикла и чтобы в цикле по убыванию сортировались. Спасибо! Хотя бы за хоть какую-то наводку :)

Comment: Я не пишу готовое решение, а даю идею. Среднее число - это разброс от минимума к максимуму. В данном случае у среднего числа возможно 24 варианта заполнения. Можно сделать 24 запроса по мета ключам, но это глупо, хотя будет работать. Я бы обновил уже текущий функционал расчета рейтинга при входе на страницу, чтобы это число записывалось отдельным полем - таким образом можно будет искать посты через это поле.

Comment: немного не понимаю. Насколько знаю. Ты заходишь на страницу, у меня через js происходит калькуляция 4х оценок и делится на 4, чтобы получилось среднее число. Все это происходит внутри цикла. Выходит, что нужно до цикла просчитать все грубо говоря услуги и потом сортироать их. Разве, сразу после вывода моментально сделать сортировку после вывода.